# Jquery event not firing when a div is display: none

Tags: jquery, swiper.js, nouislider

i made a fiddle with the source code:

https://jsfiddle.net/alexking2005/mvogea0q/

I think the problem is here:

```
var checkSlide = function (id){

                // Question 1
                if(id == 'p1_no'){
                    mySwiper.slideTo(3, 100, true);
                }
                else if(id == 'p4_no') { // Question 4
                    mySwiper.slideTo(6, 100, true);
                }
                else if(id == 'p7_no'){ // Question 7
                    mySwiper.slideTo(9, 100, true);
                }
                else if(id == 'p10_no'){ // Question 10
                    mySwiper.slideTo(12, 100, true);
                }
                else if(id == 'p13_no'){ // Question 13
                    mySwiper.slideTo(15, 100, true);
                }
                else{
                    mySwiper.slideNext(1000, true);
                }

            };
```

I have a **div named "quiz_ap"** with swiperJS, nouisler et datetimepicker in it.

When div has style="display:block" it works fine. What works fine ? I disabled right arrow to avoid user to slide next without answer to a question. When user clic on a button, the arrow is enabled or the slide automatically go to next.

But when style="display:none", events are not firing. I don't know why. 
Any idea ?

Comment: You can't click on something that is not displayed.  I don't understand the issue?

Comment: we need some more information about the div in question and the click handler

Comment: Sorry, not clear enough.  Exactly what's hidden?  What events?  Could be the 3rd party code checks that something is visible - sometimes UI components work on the height (eg of a contained image) - if it's display:none, then there's no height.

Comment: i edited the question, i hope my question will be reopen